# uftReadfileAsTable in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using the function uftReadfileAsTable to put HTML into a table so that I can update an SQL table with this entire string of HTML.  The way it's written it appears to put each line on it's own row.  I need all the lines for this flat html file to be in one row.  How can I modify this function to return the entire html file in one column, one row?

If you can advise or provide direction in where I can get information to modify this function I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you storing an entire HTML file in the database?

Comment: The entire file is a list of names that I need update a html module in a DNN database.  I'm writting an SSIS package to automate this process.  I did finally find the answer here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=112599   Works just like I wanted...